# Can't get GetSetMethod for property with private setter from base class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not able to get the `GetSetMethod` of a property from the base class with private setter, it works when the property is not form the base class.

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Prop1").GetSetMethod(true));// this is null
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Prop2").GetSetMethod(true));// this has value
}    

public class FooBase
{
    public string Prop1 { get; private set; }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public string Prop2 { get; private set; }
}
```

is it possible to get it or to set the value of the property from the base class

Comment: For what reason do you want to access that method? Woulnd´t it be already ok to just call `PropertyInfo.SetValue()`?

Comment: the reason is to find out if it has a setter, and to set its value if it does, `PropertyInfo.SetValue()` will fail saying `Property set method not found`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mark a setter as `private`, the metadata for the setter method is indeed missing in its derived types. You must locate it in its `DeclaringType` (the Type that it is `private` to).

You can try this instead:

```
var prop = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Prop1");
var setter = prop.GetSetMethod(true);

if (setter == null)
    setter = prop.DeclaringType.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetSetMethod(true);
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe, The downside I see is the need to call `GetProperty` once again. When the setter is not `private`, there's no reason to access the metadata once again.

Comment: Yeah - I realised there was a second call to `GetProperty` after I posted.  Sorry for the noise :)